# Find matching partial string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to find an answer on google, nor the mongoose website, so I am asking here. If it is possible, how can I search for a partially matching string in a document.

ex:

In a user collection:

```
{ name: "Louis", location: "Paris, France" },
{ name: "Bill", location: "Paris, Illinoid" },
{ name: "Stephen", location: "Toronto, Ontario" }
```

mongoose function:

```
searchForCity("Paris");
```

The result would be a list of documents from the User collection having "Paris" in the location String. ex:

```
[
    { name: "Louis", location: "Paris, France" },
    { name: "Homer", location: "Paris, Illinois" }
]
```

Comment: Hiya hope this helps: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries look for .find have a nice one, cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a [regex](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-regex) for that:

> **`Query#regex`**, **`Query#$regex`**
>
> Specifies the `$regex` operator.
>
> ```
> query.regex('name.first', /^a/i)
> ```

So something like this:

```
User.where('location').$regex(/Paris/);
User.where('location').$regex(/paris/i); // Case insensitive version
```

Keep in mind that regex queries can be very expensive as MongoDB will have to run the regex against every single `location`. If you can anchor your regexes at the beginning:

```
User.where('location').$regex(/^Paris/);
```

then you can index the location and MongoDB will use that index.

Comment: Worked perfectly, had to add: var expression = new RegExp(word, "i");, were word = "Paris"; this was i can include variables in there.

Comment: Is there a mongoose solution?

Comment: @chovy Um, what part of the answer *isn't* a Mongoose solution?

Comment: sorry, i was mistaken. I thought this was native mongo. Now the question is how do I conditionally add the `.$regex()` to my query? I only need it sometimes.

Comment: @chovy: If `x` is a query then so is `x.where(...).regex(...)`, right? So you'd just build the query piece by piece with things like `if(whatever) { query = query.where(...).regex(...) }`. Been a couple years since I've touched any of this but I'm pretty sure that's how it works.

Comment: ok, thanks. I didn't know you could conditionally build chains like that. makes sense.